# conn.commitAsync is not a function error when running as transaction

Tags: node.js, mocking, knex.js, node-oracledb

When I run below code I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: conn.commitAsync is not a function
    at Oracle_Transaction.commit (/home/foo/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/oracledb/transaction.js:14:18)
    at Function.transactor.commit (/home/foo/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:277:40)
    at /home/foo/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:191:35
```

I don't seem to have an issue if I run without a transaction, so I am assuming it is the implicit commits that is choked on. This runs fine regularly btw, it is only when I attempt to mock it fails.

Am I missing something? Is it the connection which is not mocked, how do I mock it, if that is the issue?

```
import * as knex from 'knex';

export const pool: any = knex({
    acquireConnectionTimeout: 60000,
    client: 'oracledb',
    connection: {
        connectString: 'zoo',
        password: 'foo',
        user: 'bar',
    },
    debug: true,
    pool: {
        acquireTimeoutMillis: 60000, 10),
        idleTimeoutMillis: 60000,
        max: 10,
        min: 10,
    },
});

    await pool.transaction((trx: any) => {
        return Promise.all([
            row = this.insertOne(trx, id, data),
            this.insertTwo(trx, id, data),
            userData.flag ? this.insertThree(trx, id, data) : {},
            this.insertFour(trx, id, data),
            moreToDo(data),
        ]);
    })
    .catch((err: any) => {
        logger.error(err);
    });
```

each of the insert functions look something like this

```
    public insertOne(trx: any,  id: number, data: any) {
    return pool('FOOBAR')
            .transacting(trx)
            .withSchema('FOO')
            .insert([
                {
                    FOO: 'BAR',
                    ID: id,
                    CREATE_DT: pool.raw('sysdate'),
                    LAST_MOD_DT: pool.raw('sysdate'),
                },
            ]);
}
```

It's mocked like this

```
import * as mockKnex from 'mock-knex';
mockKnex.mock(pool);
const tracker = mockKnex.getTracker();
tracker.install();
    tracker.on('query', (query, step) => {
        [
            function firstQuery() {
                    {
                        ID: 1234,
                    },
                ]);
            },
            function secondQuery() {
                query.response([
                    {
                        ID: 1234,
                    },
                ]);
            },
            function thirdQuery() {
                query.response([]);
            },
            function fourthQuery() {
                query.response([]);
            },
            function fifthQuery() {
                query.response([]);
            },
        ][step - 1]();
    });
    const results = await sut.inserts(subject);
    expect(results).toEqual(foo);
```

I have tried using nested .then statements as well, like the knex documentation does it with an explicit commit or rollback, same problem.

Comment: Even if it running 'fine' when not mocked, make sure you understand why using `Promise.all` on a single connection (if that's what Knex is doing) is not recommended, see the [node-oracledb doc](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#parallelism).

Comment: Does this also apply to pools? ie Will it only run on a single connection even when using a pool? My guess is, the mocking library (mock-knex) is not properly mocking out the connections in the pool when using transactions. Is there a better library out there?

Comment: A connection is a connection so, yes, it applies to pools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody running into the same issue, I was able to get this working by adding a jest.spyOn on the rollback and commit function in the Transaction class in oracledb

```
// tslint:disable: no-var-requires
// tslint:disable: no-require-imports
// tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
const Transaction  = require('../../node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/oracledb/transaction.js');

const rollbackMock = jest.spyOn(Transaction.prototype, 'rollback');
const commitkMock = jest.spyOn(Transaction.prototype, 'commit');
```

in the beforeEach()

```
jest.resetAllMocks();
rollbackMock.mockImplementation(() => null);
commitkMock.mockImplementation(() => null);
```